# React component not scrolling to top on re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, electron

I have a React class component which is separated into left half and right half, left side has options to select like from Fruits, Vegetables, Junk and on right side, a list of that item is shown.
**Issue:** Suppose I click on Fruits and scroll the right side to mid of list, then again clicking on Fruits take me to the place where I previously was.
**Expected:** Clicking on Fruit again should show the list from top.

I tried window.scrollTo(0,0) and window.scrollBy(0, topRef.current.offsetTop) but it is scrolling the entire window including left side.
How can I just scroll the right side of items on re-render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [ScrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) instead of scrollTo and scrollBy.

add an Id to the element where you intend to scroll and use scrollIntoView with that id

```js
document.getElementById(elId).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "nearest"});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add a margin for block: auto option.
I had a header which was a separate component even that is getting scrolled up.